# Eliminar pantalla negra antes del Splash de app - Android

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

Estoy tratando de minimizar o quitar por completo el pantallazo negro que va por defecto antes del Splash en mi app siguiendo este "tutorial" ==> [primera respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307126/black-screen-before-splash-screen-appear-in-android)

Seguí este consejo pero no me esta dando resultados y creo que es porque en el Manifest no tengo la referencia de forma correcta.

Este es mi archivo `XML` llamado `TemaArranque.xml`, contine la referencia a una imagen PNG en el folder Mipmap llamada `fondotheme` que es basicamente una captura de pantalla de mi splash para lograr el efecto de que el splash se muestra inmediatamente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme is the default theme. -->
<style name="Theme" parent="android:style/Theme" />

<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="Theme">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@mipmap/fondotheme</item>

</style>
</resources>
```

Siguiendo el tutorial al inicio del archivo va esta linea con lo que se supone/entiendo es la referencia del tema:

```
<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="Theme">
```

Mi AndroidManifest:

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" 
               android:label="MyName" android:icon="@mipmap/LogoSombra1" 
               android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:theme="@style/Theme.MyAppTheme" 
    android:largeHeap="true">
```

Entonces, es aqui donde no estoy seguro que esta linea este correcta:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.MyAppTheme"
```

[image: 1]

Comment: el atributo `android:windowBackground` no puede ser un `@mipmap`. Debe ser un `@color` o `@drawable`

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem funciona perfecto PERO solo en el proyecto de prueba. No entiendo por que...

Comment: Listo, era problema de referencia en el Main Activity. Comparto la solucion.

Comment: Buenas noticias! Ayer se lanzó la librería oficíal [Core Splashscreen](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core#core-splashscreen-1.0.0-alpha01) que provee backward compatibility para las [nuevas APIs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features/splash-screen) de android 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema estaba en que no se estaba referenciando ese `Theme` en el `MainActivity`, al final quedo funcionando excelente de este modo:

Archivo `XML`:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppThemeA" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/fondotheme</item>
    </style>
```

MainActivity.cs:

```
[Activity(Label = "NombreApp", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = false, Theme = "@style/AppThemeA")]
```

***--No fue necesario cambiar nada en el Manifest.--***